# Update MFC's CSliderCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, slider

I am working on a C++ MFC project and bumping in the following. I have a CSliderCtrl on my form which I call MFC_scKINECTANGLE. To make it the way I want it the next piece of code is used:

```
MFC_scKINECTANGLE = (CSliderCtrl * ) GetDlgItem(SC_kinectAngle);
MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetRangeMax(27);
MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetRangeMin(-27);        
MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetPos(0);
```

The problem is that the slider at the start of the program is at the top of the bar whereas it should be in the middle, and when you try to grab it, it suddenly jumps to the correct position and works fine after that. How can I make sure the slider is in the middle of the bar at the start of my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN [`CSliderCtrl::SetRangeMax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/144y7b24%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (`CSliderCtrl::SetRangeMin` is similar):

```
void SetRangeMax(
   int nMax,
   BOOL bRedraw = FALSE 
);
```

You need to set `bRedraw` parameter to `TRUE` to update slider.

Another (and probably better) variant - force redraw the slider after setup.

But due to bug (or feature?) in MS trackbar implementation you cannot just call [`CWnd::Invalidate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ax04k970%28v=vs.90%29) (for deferred redraw) or even [`CWnd::RedrawWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fdz8ey6%28v=vs.90%29) (for immediate redraw). This will have no effect.

Fortunately there are several events that force trackbar to repaint, e.g. enabling/disabling the window:

```
const BOOL isEnabled = MFC_scKINECTANGLE->IsWindowEnabled();

MFC_scKINECTANGLE->EnableWindow(!isEnabled);
MFC_scKINECTANGLE->EnableWindow(isEnabled);
```

See [this discussion](http://www.microsoftfaqs.com/msg/14841210.aspx) for details.

Comment: For some reason

    MFC_scKINECTANGLE->RedrawWindow();

Does not work. However:

    MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetPos(0);
    MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetRangeMax(27);
    MFC_scKINECTANGLE->SetRangeMin(-27,TRUE);
Does work. So I am curious why RedrawWindow() does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the range (0 - 100) and position (50) in the dialog's constructor.  The slider kept showing up initially at position 0 instead.  If I called GetPos() right after SetPos() it was returning 0 instead of 50.

What made it work for me was overriding OnInitDialog() and setting the range & position there instead of in the constructor.

```
BOOL CVolumeDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    m_VSliderBarNormal.SetRange(0, 100, TRUE);
    m_VSliderBarNormal.SetPos(50);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
                  // EXCEPTION: OCX Property Pages should return FALSE
}
```

Comment: `I was setting the range (0 - 100) and position (50) in the dialog's constructor.` - I just wonder how your code was able to run. Magic valid HWND or highly customized constructor and dialog class ?

Comment: Standard MFC dialog and slider classes: CDialogEx and CSliderCtrl.  The only magic is from VC++ 2015 Class Wizard in creating the derived classes.  I suppose that's why they call it a wizard. Instructions here: http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/tutorial_3.html